# CodeIgniter - Single result

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to use CodeIgniter to create a web application that show some articles.
I extracted all articles from the DB, they are used as previews.
Now i want to create a page that show a single article.
The previews of the articles are shown in **/articles/**, i would like to show a single article in **/articles/read/id**

This is my code:

**Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Articles extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index() 
    {             
        $this->load->model('articles_model');

        $articles_data['data'] = $this->articles_model->select_articles();

        $this->load->view('header');

        $this->load->view('nav');

        $this->load->view('articles-content', $articles_data);

        $this->load->view('footer');

    }

    public function read()
    {
        //?????
    }
```

**Model**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Articles_model extends CI_Model 
{

    public function select_articles()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('articles');
        $this->db->join('authors', 'articles.id_author = authors.id_author', 'left');
        $this->db->join('images', 'articles.id_image = images.id_image', 'left');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();

    }

}
```

**View**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<div id="content">
   <div id="articles">
      <?php foreach($data as $row){
         $limited_article = word_limiter($row['article_text'], 200);
      ?>
      <section class="article">
         <h2><?php echo $row['article_title'];?></h2>
         <img class="article-image" src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/images/' . $row['image']) ;?>">
         <p class="info">Author: <?php echo $row['author']; ?> Date: <?php echo $row['article_data'] ?></p>
         <p><?php echo $limited_article; ?></p>
      </section>
      <?php }?>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a param (`$id`) your `read($id)` method In controller :

```
public function read($id) {
    $this->load->model('articles_model');

    $data['article'] = $this->articles_model->get_select_articles($id);

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('nav');
    $this->load->view('articles-single', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Create new method `get_select_articles()` in your model like bellow :

```
class Articles_model extends CI_Model 
{
    public function get_select_articles($id){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('articles');
        $this->db->join('authors', 'articles.id_author = authors.id_author', 'left');
        $this->db->join('images', 'articles.id_image = images.id_image', 'left');
        $this->db->where('articles.id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

Create a new page `articles-single.php` for show single article data in view folder. I have used `$article['article_details'];` in `articles-single.php` for view article details. You will use `article_details` or some thinks like that as per your db field name.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<div id="content">
   <div id="articles">
      <section class="article">
            <?php if($article) { ?>
            <h2><?php echo $article['article_title'];?></h2>
            <img class="article-image" src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/images/' . $article['image']) ;?>">
            <p class="info">Author: <?php echo $article['author']; ?> Date: <?php echo $article['article_data'] ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $article['article_details']; ?></p>
            <?php } ?>
      </section>
      <?php }?>
   </div>
</div>
```